# Error message using Vue-chartjs in vue-property-decorator to implement chart as component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-chartjs

I want to use a chart in my vue Project. At the Moment iam using Vue with TypeScript, Vue-property-decorator and vue-chartjs. I found a page where i can use both (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs-typescript). Now i simply tryed to implement a Barchart.

I want to store the chart script in a separate Component (Dashboard_BarChart.vue). The Code lookslike this:

```
<script lang="ts">
//import Vue from "vue";
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";

Component({
    extends: Bar
});
export default class BarChart extends Vue<Bar> {
    mounted() {
        // Overwriting base render method with actual data.
        this.renderChart({
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "GitHub Commits",
                    backgroundColor: "#f87979",
                    data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11]
                }
            ]
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

In my Dahsboard.vue (where i want to implement the component) i wrote the following code:

```
<template>
    <q-page class="flex flex-center standardBackgroundDark">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <div>
            <BarChart></BarChart>
        </div>
    </q-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
//import Vue from "vue";
import BarChart from "../../components/Dashboard_BarChart.vue";
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component({
    components: { BarChart }
})
export default class CommitChart extends Vue {}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

So if i implement the component this way i got this error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFTke.png)

I hope anyone can help me. Something went wront with

```
@Component({
    components: { BarChart }
})
```